# Erlang: No Match of right hand side value error

Tags: list, erlang

I'm trying to create a representation of some towers in erlang and when I try to run the following command, a no match of right hand side value appears.

```
T = towers:create(5).
```

Code:

```
create( N ) ->
    [{tower1, Tower1 = lists:seq(1,N)}, {tower2, Tower2 = []}, {tower3, Tower3 = []}].
```

Comment: As @zxq9 said, this limited code snippet will emit several `Warning: variable 'TowerX' is unused` messages from the compiler. It is not clear whence the `no match of right hand side` errors come from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning variables that go unused, which will cause a compiler warning, but not actually fail. This works just fine:

```
-module(towers).
-export([create/1]).

create( N ) ->
    [{tower1, lists:seq(1,N)}, {tower2, []}, {tower3, []}].
```

In use:

```
1> c(towers).
{ok,towers}
2> towers:create(5).
[{tower1,[1,2,3,4,5]},{tower2,[]},{tower3,[]}]
```